How do I write the JSON to call an API token/create path and return a token?
I'm trying to create a Nintex Xtension that I can use to call /api/token/create to get the bearer token. I will use the bearer token as a variable to call the next web service. I just don't know how to write the JSON code to pull the token back. This is what I have so far. I feel like this should be so simple, but I've spent hours and I just can't seem to solve it.
ChatGPT to the rescue :) I can't believe I didn't try that first! It would have saved me a lot of time. Here's the code that worked.
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "Create Token API",
    "description": "API for creating a token"
  },
  "host": "xxx",
  "basePath": "/api",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/token/create": {
      "post": {
        "summary": "Create Token",
        "description": "Endpoint to create a token",
        "consumes": [
          "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "username",
            "in": "formData",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "description": "User's email address"
          },
          {
            "name": "password",
            "in": "formData",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "description": "User's password"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Token created successfully",
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Invalid input"
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "Unauthorized"
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "basicAuth": []
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "securityDefinitions": {
    "basicAuth": {
      "type": "basic"
    }
  }
}

